# Can JSTL transform XML encoded in UTF-8?

Tags: encoding

I am making a simple JSP application to transform XML data into HTML.
I use JSTL and my XML data is encoded in UTF-8. It works, but the danish characters look strange in the browser.

Like this:

Danish characters written directly in jsp: ÆØÅ æøå
Same danish characters transformed with jstl:
character: Ã† character: Ã¦
character: Ã˜ character: Ã¸
character: Ã… character: Ã¥

However, if I manually change the xml definition like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
```

The output is transformed properly.

Should I set up JSTL in some way to handle UTF-8, or is it,that my file is actually latin1 encoded by mistake? I do not know how to check this...

Here is my test xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rows>
<row>
    <name>character: Æ</name>
    <surname>character: æ</surname>
</row>
<row>
    <name>character: Ø</name>
    <surname>character: ø</surname>
</row>
<row>
    <name>character: Å</name>
    <surname>character: å</surname>
</row>
</rows>
```

Here is my xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <table border="0">
        <xsl:for-each select="rows/row">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="surname" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My index.jsp:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org  /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Written directly in jsp: ÆØÅ æøå
<h3>xml transformed with jstl:</h3>
<c:import url="/Test.xsl" var="xsltdoc" />
<c:import url="/Test.xml" var="xmldoc" />
<x:transform xml="${xmldoc}" xslt="${xsltdoc}" />
</body>
</html>
```

I am using JSTL libraries (Implementation-Version: 1.2) on JBOSS AP 4.2.3.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I checked the encoding of my xml data [here](http://sodved.awardspace.info/unicode.pl), and it is correct, that it is UTF-8 encoded.

Apparently, in index.jsp JSTL must be set to use UTF-8 like so

```
<c:import url="/Metadata1.xsl" var="xsltdoc" charEncoding="UTF-8" />
<c:import url="/Metadata1.xml" var="xmldoc" charEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

This solves my problem.

Comment: Thank you, I had the same problem with French letters, and your solution solves my problem.